# When i add a node in my treeview something strange happen

Tags: jquery-ui

It is my first time that i'm asking here for some help! Sorry about my bad english, but i will try to explain my problem...

I want to add a new node to my treeview, so i'm using the 'add' options from treeview documentation, here is the code:

```
var tree = $('#fileTreeId').treeview({prerendered: true});
var newSublist =  $('<li><span id="'+id+'" class="folder" >'+nomePasta+'</span><ul><li><span class="file">&nbsp;</span></li></ul></li>').appendTo($('#fileTreeId'));
$('#fileTreeId').treeview({add: newSublist});
```

So, it's works fine, but in my system i have a click event that when i click on the folder i check the parent "ul" to ckeck if it is "expandable" or "collapsable", if it is "collapsable"  i get by ajax the date from database...

So after explain i will tell my doubt now. When i call the function "treeview", it reverts my logic, for example, previously when i click on the folder it gives me "expandable" when the folder is closed and give me "collapsable" when the folder is open, now, after i call the function "treeview", it gives the opposite result, it is, when the folder is closed the class is "collapsable" and when the folder is open the class of parent "ul" is "expandable", anyone have any idea of what it can be?